# Minimum number with 0 and 1 divisible by n

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I just came around this question and was curious to know the solution.I tried solving using multiple ways but was getting TLE for many test cases.

You have to generate minimum number using only 0's and 1's which is divisible by n.

So input is n where n<=10^6.

Output->number consisting of only 1's and 0's divisible by n.

For example
n=4 output=100
n=5 output=10.

My approach->
1) Do a BFS with tree root as 1 and left child as 0 and right as 1 and same for the children.

2)Starting from 1 convert the number to binary and compare. 
Any suggestions or approach would be helpful.

Comment: Why not trying to multiply n in a loop until you find a result with only '0's and '1's?

Comment: This seems like it belongs on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Trick question. The answer is 0 for any n.

Comment: There are only 64 such positive numbers < 10^6 - you can just generate them from smallest to largest and break out when there's a remainder of zero in the test division.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I don't think that a more efficient solution exists. You should propose it as an answer. But note : only n is <10^6. The answer might be longer if no other constraint is specified.

Comment: Yeah, as a trivial example, for n=9 there's no solution below 10**6

Comment: @500-InternalServerError restriction is only on n not on the answer

Comment: @Kevin the answer has to be greater than 0.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Your approach would give a TLE.